# Reactjs pass value of button

Tags: reactjs

How can I do that when I press the student button, 10 print to the `console.log` from `handleSwitcher` and if it was teacher, print 20?

```
  const handleSwitcher = async()=>{
    console.log()
  }

    <Grid xs={4} style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
        <Button style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
          <CImg
          height={50}
          style={{margin: 10,}}
          value="10"
          onClick={handleSwitcher}
          />
          <div className={classes.constantia}>Student</div>
        </Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid xs={4} style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
        <Button style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
          <CImg
          height={50}
          style={{margin: 10,}}
          value="20"
          onClick={handleSwitcher}
          />
          <div className={classes.constantia}>Teacher</div>
        </Button>
      </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
const handleSwitcher = async()=>{
    console.log()
  }
```

to

```
const handleSwitcher = (e) => console.log(e.target.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try change `handleSwitcher` to:

```
  const handleSwitcher = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
```

Simple example of the code is :

```
export default function App() {
  const handleSwitcher = (e) => {
    // in student button click, result will be 10 
    // in teacher button click result will be 20
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button value="10" onClick={handleSwitcher}>
        Student
      </button>
      <button value="20" onClick={handleSwitcher}>
        Teacher
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit romantic-easley-ovsir]